# Comma separate two separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

In an SQL Server 2012 table I want to take all the rows from two columns and turn them into one row, still two columns, but each column being comma-separated.

For example

```
Customerid    |    FacilityId
-----------------------------
1                    5678
2                    9101
5                    6543
```

Then afterwards id like the results to be like this

```
Customerid    |    FacilityId
-----------------------------
1,2,5            5678,9101,6543
```

Comment: How many rows are you likely to have in your table?

Comment: Not many, maybe 3 or 4 at most.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `FOR XML` like this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c9478a/1)

**Query**

```
SELECT STUFF((
SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Customerid)
FROM Customer
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as Customerid,
STUFF((
SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),FacilityId)
FROM Customer
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as FacilityId
```

**Output**

```
Customerid  FacilityId
1,2,5   5678,9101,6543
```

**EDIT**

You can even use variable to concatenate the csv together which doesn't require 2 table scans like the `FOR XML` however you may encounter issues with it when using with `ORDER BY` or other functions in the same query.

Since you have only 3-4 rows, I would suggest going with `FOR XML` approach

```
DECLARE @Customerid VARCHAR(MAX) = '',@FacilityId VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT 
@Customerid += ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Customerid),
@FacilityId += ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),FacilityId)
FROM Customer

SELECT STUFF(@Customerid,1,1,'') as Customerid, STUFF(@FacilityId,1,1,'') as FacilityId
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect, worked a treat. I did not realise i could just add a second STUFF in like that. Learn something new every day :)

Comment: @stew STUFF is a function, it replaces a number of characters with a new set of characters. In this case it replaces the first character with empty varchar

Comment: Better than my answer ! as @Stew said: Learning something new everyday. ;) Cheers

Comment: hope SQL Server gets something similar to `group_concat` or `LISTAGG` which is cleaner and more readable

Comment: I posted a (in my opinion) improved version of your second method

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Nice way to remove the use of `STUFF`, I used to use `ISNULL` but `CONCAT` handles that internally

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple and fast way using [CONCAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(CONCAT_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true), it will work from sqlserver 2012:

```
DECLARE @t table(Customerid int, FacilityId int)
INSERT @t values(1,5678),(2,9101),(5,6543)

DECLARE @x1 varchar(max), @x2 varchar(max)

SELECT 
  @x1 = concat(@x1 + ',', Customerid), 
  @x2 = concat(@x2 + ',', FacilityId)
FROM @t

SELECT @x1, @x2
```

Comment: Tricky approach with CONCAT wich handles NULL values. Cool

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT Customerid = STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + CAST(md.Customerid as varchar(max))
          FROM dbo.TableName md
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''),
        Facilityid=STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + CAST(md.Facilityid as varchar(max))
          FROM dbo.TableName md
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM dbo.TableName m
JOIN dbo.TableName s ON s.customerid = m.customerid AND s.facilityid=m.facilityid) as Tbl
GROUP BY customerid,facilityid
```

Result:

```
Customerid  Facilityid
--------------------------
1,2,5       5678,9101,6543
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3c824/12)

Answer (score 0):

Use `FOR XML PATH` in SQL SERVER

```
SELECT (SELECT CAST(Customerid AS VARCHAR) + ',' from 
                   Table for XML PATH(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)') AS Customerid, 
    (SELECT CAST(FacilityId AS VARCHAR) + ',' from 
                   Table for XML PATH(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)') AS FacilityId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `STUFF` with `FOR XML` to achieve this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpDemo (CustomerId INT, FacilityId INT)
INSERT INTO #tmpDemo VALUES (1, 5678), (2, 9101), (5, 6543)

SELECT  DISTINCT
        STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + CAST(T.CustomerId AS VARCHAR)
          FROM #tmpDemo T
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as CustomerId,
        STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + CAST(T.FacilityId AS VARCHAR)
          FROM #tmpDemo T
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as FacilityId
FROM #tmpDemo m

DROP TABLE #tmpDemo
```

This may cause some serious performance issues on large data sets, but I note from your comment above that you will only ever have a handful of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Use `COALESCE`

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000) 
DECLARE @id VARCHAR(8000) 

SELECT @id = COALESCE(@id + ', ', '') + CAST(col1 AS VARCHAR),@Names = COALESCE(@Names + ', ', '') + col2
FROM tab1

select @id,@Names
```

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83c52/3)**